# Fadein div once everything is loaded

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

I'm using a simple load to fill a div with content using a fadein as the callback. I then have a secondary fadein for the images to reduce their pop in.

I'd like to remove this pop in entirely and have the page fadein only once all images have been loaded, so it all loads as one piece. How do i achieve this?

```
$("#content").load("pages/test.htm", function () {
    $("#page").fadeTo(250, 1, "swing");
});
```

then on the loaded page

```
$('img').load(function (e) {
    $('img').fadeIn();
});
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a confusing question but wouldn't the following work?

```
$('img').load(function() {
    $("#page").fadeTo(250,1,'swing');
});
```

Comment: Worked perfect! I could have sworn i tried this before, something must have been wrong when i did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // do your fade in here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#content").load("pages/test.htm", function () {
    $("#page").fadeTo(250, 1, "swing",function(){
        $('img').fadeIn();
    });
});
```